# React router - ajax deeplinking

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-router, deep-linking

I have react app using react router and reflux with versions little bit old. 
We have a table and a search button. When search button is clicked, ajax request is being made to get the results. At this time, I need to append the search results query to the URL to make users able to bookmark it.

I know using, "window.location.hash", we can append query params to browser URL. I wanted to avoid "#".

But is there a way in React router to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to bookmark the search query, you can use react-router with different route for Query Result page where table with data is rendered.

```
render() {
     <Route path='/search/:query' component={TableWithData}/>
}
```

TableData is react component which displays data in Table. React router takes care of changing URL (without hash) and users can bookmark link if they want to.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am able to append to browser URL using "this.history.pushState".

Comment: when using encodeURI("some string"), pushState does not seem to add encoded url in the browser ?

Comment: why do you need to push to this.history.push ? You can can use - <Route path='/search/:query' component={TableWithData}/>. Can you show proto code ?

Comment: my requirement for the search functionality, is to append the search text to the URL so that users can bookmark it. That is the reason I need to do pushstate to the history so that this searchText will appear in the URL